# JSTL and href passing parameter

Tags: jsp, jstl, parameter-passing, href

Using JSP and servlets and NetBeans IDE.

I pass a parameter through href as follows.

```
<a href="coursematerial.jsp?param1=${row.COURSEID}"><c:out value="${row.COURSEID}"/>
```

Now in the next jsp,i want to save the parameter i passed.how could i do that and send the saved parameter to the hidden input in the form?
i tried using

```
<input type="hidden" name="courseid" value=<%= request.getParameter("param1")%> >
```

but since there is another href to be carried out before the form is filled, the value is retrieved as null.

Is there a way of saving the required parameter as a session(without scripting but using JSTL) and retrieving without passing it as a href ?

Comment: can you try by using <jsp:param name="param" value="<%=request.getParameter('param1')%> in jsp forward action?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if its possible using jstl. But you can use flash scope. That attribute will be there still next jsp as per your requirement.
Use this simple code to implement flash scope.

For example, to add a message to flash scope, just use the regular syntax for adding a request scoped attribute and let the fiter take care of it:

```
request.setAttribute("flash.message", "Here is the news...");
```

The above attribute can then be accessed in the redirect target JSP using EL or scriptlet syntax (omitting the ‘flash.‘ prefix):

```
${message}
or
<%= request.getAttribute("message") %>
```

Here’s the code for the filter:

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Ensures that any request parameters whose names start
 * with 'flash.' are available for the next request too. 
 */
public class FlashScopeFilter implements Filter {

    private static final String FLASH_SESSION_KEY = "FLASH_SESSION_KEY";

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, 
                    FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        //reinstate any flash scoped params from the users session 
        //and clear the session
        if (request instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
            HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
            HttpSession session = httpRequest.getSession(false);
            if (session != null) {
                Map<String, Object> flashParams = (Map<String, Object>) 
                                    session.getAttribute(FLASH_SESSION_KEY);
                if (flashParams != null) {
                    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> flashEntry : flashParams.entrySet()) {
                        request.setAttribute(flashEntry.getKey(), flashEntry.getValue());
                    }
                    session.removeAttribute(FLASH_SESSION_KEY);
                }
            }
        }

        //process the chain
        chain.doFilter(request, response);

        //store any flash scoped params in the user's session for the 
        //next request
        if (request instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
            HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
            Map<String, Object> flashParams = new HashMap();
            Enumeration e = httpRequest.getAttributeNames();
            while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
                String paramName = (String) e.nextElement();
                if (paramName.startsWith("flash.")) {
                    Object value = request.getAttribute(paramName);
                    paramName = paramName.substring(6, paramName.length());
                    flashParams.put(paramName, value);
                }
            }
            if (flashParams.size() > 0) {
                HttpSession session = httpRequest.getSession(false);
                session.setAttribute(FLASH_SESSION_KEY, flashParams);
            }
        }
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        //no-op
    }

    public void destroy() {
        //no-op
    }
}
```

http://smartkey.co.uk/development/implementing-flash-scope-in-java-web-applications/